# How can I make dynamic page number pagination

Tags: php, pagination

I have some pagination working just fine, only issue is I can only get it to show and fixed number of pages to choose from. Right now I have put it to 10 pages, but I would like i to change dynamically based on $total_records2.

So lets say I have 100 records and the limit pr page is 5 ($limit2 = 5;)
There will be 20 pages.  Right now I can only get it to show this way 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20.

But what I want is the paging to change dynamically based on records and based on what page you are at.

So it looks more like this:

At page 1:
**1** 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 Last

At page 9:
First 4 5 6 7 8 **9** 10 11 12 13 Last

At page 20:
First 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 **20**

I have tried a lot of things, but can not seem to find the right solution.
Can someone tell me how to do on current code I have ?

Thank you

```
    <?
        $limit2 = 5;

        $total_records2 = count(user_ended_tips());
        $total_pages2 = ceil($total_records2 / $limit2);
        if (isset($_GET["page2"])) { $page2  = $_GET["page2"]; } else { $page2=1; };  
        $start_from2 = ($page2-1) * $limit2;   
    ?>

    <div class="col-md-6">

      <div id="target-content2" >loading...</div>


      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
          <ul class='pagination text-center' id="pagination2">
            <?php if(!empty($total_pages2)):for($j=1; $j<=10; $j++):  
            if($j == $page2):?>
                  <li class='active' id="<?php echo $j;?>"><a href='pagination_ended_user_tips?page2=<?php echo $j;?>' target='target-content2'><?php echo $j;?></a></li> 
            <?php else:?>
            <li id="<?php echo $j;?>"><a href='pagination_ended_user_tips?page2=<?php echo $j;?>'><?php echo $j;?></a></li>
            <?php endif;?>      
            <?php endfor;endif;?> 
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#target-content2").load("pagination_ended_user_tips?page2=1");
    $("#pagination2 li").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#target-content2").html('loading...');
    $("#pagination2 li").removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
        var pageNum = this.id;
        $("#target-content2").load("pagination_ended_user_tips?page2=" + pageNum);
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<?php
        $limit2 = 5;

        $total_records2 = count(user_ended_tips());

        if (isset($_GET["page"])) { $page  = $_GET["page"]; } else { $page=1; };  

    ?>

  <div class="col-md-6">

    <div id="target-content2">loading...</div>


    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
        <ul class='pagination text-center' id="pagination2">

          for($j=0; $j<=total_records2; $j++){  
             <li class='<?Php echo $page==$j?'active':'';' id="<?php echo $j;?>">
            <a href='pagination_ended_user_tips?page=<?php echo $j;?>' target='target-content2'>
              <?php echo $j;?>
            </a>
          </li>
          <?php } ?>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#target-content2").load("pagination_ended_user_tips?page2=1");
        $("#pagination2 li").click(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $("#target-content2").html('loading...');
          $("#pagination2 li").removeClass('active');
          $(this).addClass('active');
          var pageNum = this.id;
          $("#target-content2").load("pagination_ended_user_tips?page2=" + pageNum);
        });
      });
    </script>
```

Comment: It is not running. Im getting some php errors. with endif

Comment: Still something not running.
think it is around here:
<li class='<?Php echo $page==$j?>'active':'';' id="<?php echo $j;?>">

Comment: Think it was because missing $ and  ?>
now it is running. but it is not showing anything

Comment: I hope you will able to correct these simple error `<li class='<?php echo $page==$j?'active':'';?>' id="<?php echo $j;?>">`

Comment: Yes found that issue. and also this $j<=total_records2; with missing $
but it does not show any thing now

Comment: removed check for `total_pages2`